# Multiple Async WebRequests to Handle Sync Scenario

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm working on a WP7 application that syncs with a cloud-based REST API.  To handle the sync there are several calls that have to be sequenced as the result of the last call is used in the next.  I'm using RestSharp to handle the call and closures to nest.  I'm ending up is a pattern that looks like:

```
void SyncMe()
{
  MyProvider tp = new MyProvider(_userInfo.UserKey);
  AccountInfoProvider.GetAccountInfo(_userInfo, (accountInfoArgs) =>
  {
    if (accountInfoArgs.Status == ResponseStatus.Success) {

      var set1 = from t in coll
                     where t.SyncStatus == SyncStatus.New
                     select t;

      tp.AddRange(set1, (response) =>
      {
        if (response.Status == ResponseStatus.Success) // Keep going
        {
          HandleStep1(response.MySet);

          var set2 = from t in coll
                             where t.SyncStatus == SyncStatus.Deleted
                             select t;

          tp.DeleteRange(set2, (deleteResponse) =>
          {
            if (deleteResponse.Status == ResponseStatus.Success) {

              // Check if items were updated on the server since last sync
              if (accountInfo.LastEdited > _userInfo.UserLastSync) {
                tp.Query(new Query() { ModifiedAfter = _userInfo.UserLastSync }, (results) =>
                {
                  if (results.Status == OperationStatus.Success) {
                    HandleStep2(tp);
                  }
                  else {
                  }
                });
              }
              else {
                HandleStep2(tp);
              }
              //callback(new SyncCompletedEventArgs(ResponseStatus.Success));
            }
            else {
            }
          });
        }
        else {
        }
      });
    }
    else {
    }
  });
}
```

}

which admittedly is pretty ugly.  Is there a better way to do this?  I've tried ManualResetEvents and can't seem to get them to work (when I call WaitOne() the app just hangs).  I've been looking up Rx and I'm trying to figure out if it can help in any way here but the documentation isn't screaming a solution out at me.  The whole Async model here is complicating the implementation here where sync calls would be simple.  Any thoughts on a more elegant approach?

Thanks,
K

Comment: Did you call the .Set() method on the ManualResetEvent when you get the response from the REST call? If you didn't then it would wait endlessly.

Comment: What is the type (data type) of the response get back from each request/response that the next request need to be given?

Comment: You need to call Reset() when you start the job and Set() when you're done, so WaitOne() will unblock.

Comment: I was calling the Set() method to unblock but the code never got that far. I may have to dig into RestSharp to see if the callback is is executing in a way that is blocking.  The datatype of the returned collection from each web service call is an ienumerable<T> which is what got me looking at Rx if I converted to iobservable<T>.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You might find the Reactive Extensions useful in this scenario. Jesse Liberty has a [great series of posts on the Reactive Extensions](http://jesseliberty.com/reactive-extensions-rx/), the latest of which discusses [Asynchronous Callbacks with Rx](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/02/23/asynchronous-callbacks-with-rx/).